# Moodle SSO Using asp.net web app

Tags: asp.net, moodle, moodle-api

Hi there i'm beginner in using **moodle** i want my custom website which is on ASP.net can anyone guide me that how can i add **SSO** feature for my website.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several options for Moodle. Depends on what authentication method you are using in your asp.net project?

These come with Moodle and might be suitable for .net:

LDAP - https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/LDAP_authentication

NTLM - https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/NTLM_authentication

Or use SAML, but you will need to install the SAML plugin and install simplesamlphp on your web server.

https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_saml

Comment: Hi russel is there any way i can find complete configuration of ldap server